# AMP story disable fullscreen mode

Tags: css, amp-html, amp-stories

I am creating an AMP story for my project with fullHD screens. I am trying to disable the "fullscreen mode" which is automatically turned on when the browser has some specific resolution. I need to get only fullscreen story without the background and buttons etc. I use screen 9:16 (1080x1920).

Example:
https://people.com/amp-stories/royal-a-to-z/

Screenshots:

Right - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PZmG1HOfC7TkwEgD-xTeWfalI-kkaVaD/view?usp=sharing

Wrong - https://drive.google.com/file/d/128Qcg4cl4H2pUC0TxYvPG0vg_PIXPJML/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to control which experience is used from the source code of the story; these default experiences are baked into the JavaScript of `amp-story`.  If you are hoping to use this in e.g. a kiosk environment where you are looking to modify the behavior in a single browser window, you can increase your browser's zoom level to accommodate the larger screen resolution, and the desktop experience should not get triggered.